# SQL server database deployment

Tags: database, deployment

I build a application that uses a sql server database. It working fine in my system where all necessary software are installed.

Now I want to deploy that to other system. Is it necessary to install full sql server(unnecessary heavy one, only to run that application) in that system or any support is there?

OR

can I copy the database mdf file to some location in new system and give proper connection string will work?

I am newbie to this field, please guide me.

Comment: The MDF files don't just "magically" work as SQL Server when you drop them somewhere - you need to have the SQL Server core system available; either once on a central server, or on every PC (SQL Server Express, SQL Server Compact Edition)

Comment: Ya right, it's don't work magically.So I need to install SQL server engine also or any runtime environment is enough? Please tell me edition that install silently in client machine during application installation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are free [Express & Compact](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2008/en/us/editions.aspx) versions of SQL Server (size & capability limited) that are designed specifically to run on a desktop machine where the data is local & its not appropriate to use a full server version.

You can install these using the installer of your choice, then connect & attach your mdf file directly.

Comment: So Express OR Compact (free version) is enough... Thanks I will implement these.

Answer (score 1):

You have to install SQL server on the new server, and then deploy the mdf.
SQL server cannot attach db file via network.